# How to filter the data from array using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have declared an array as  `var user_profile = [];` and I have already some pushed data in array which contains :

```
[  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]
```

I only need the data in array whose **assessCatId=1,2,3 and assessReason is not Empty** . So I tried by filtering it:

```
const output = user_profile.filter(({ assessCatId,assessReason })  => assessCatId != 0 || assessReason != 'empty');
            console.log("here the outpuit is");
            console.log(output)  ;
```

But it is not filtering the array.Still every data is coming in the array.How can i manage this array to filter the data?

Comment: assessReason is always not equal to "empty" in the data you've provided.

Comment: assessReason  is either null or "" so i tried it by comparing 'empty' .

Comment: You're comparing it to the literal string "empty", not null or the empty string. Big difference.

Comment: Why don't you tried simple `for loop`and done step by step so you can debug the code. Once you'll learn that then you can use these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert any value in array and check it

```js
let k=[  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]

let arr=[1,2,3]
let d=k.filter(a=>arr.indexOf(a.assessCatId) > -1 && a.assessReason!="" && a.assessReason!=null)
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `&&` instead of `||`. Try

```
(assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && (assessReason != '' && assessReason != null)
```

```js
var user_profile =[  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]

const output = user_profile.filter(({ assessCatId,assessReason })  => (assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && (assessReason != '' && assessReason != null));
console.log("here the outpuit is");
console.log(output)  ;
```

You can also shortened the condition like

```
(assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && assessReason)
```

```js
var user_profile =[  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]

const output = user_profile.filter(({ assessCatId,assessReason })  => (assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && assessReason);
console.log("here the outpuit is");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: assessCatId with 0 is coming twice in beginning while running your snippet

Comment: @ashwinkarki, that is because, those are two separate objects satisfies the condition.

Comment: Just update the condition to this: `(assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && (assessReason != '' && assessReason != null)`. I think he want only categories **1, 2, and 3**.

Comment: @Shidersz, you are right.....don't know I missed that......updated the answer.....thanks.

Comment: you should use `||` instead of '&&' for `(assessReason != '' && assessReason != null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `assessCatId > 0 && assessReason`

Code:

```js
const user_profile = [{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": -1,"assessReason": "2","assessAmount": "","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": -1,"assessReason": "2","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": -1,"assessReason": "","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": null,"assessAmount": "","assessPenalty": "","assessTotal": 0},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": null,"assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": "","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": "","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": "2075-09-09","assessAmount": "2075-09-17","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": "2075-09-09","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 0,"assessReason": "2075-09-17","assessTotal": null},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 1,"assessReason": "","assessAmount": "0","assessPenalty": "0","assessTotal": 0},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 2,"assessReason": "","assessAmount": "0","assessPenalty": "0","assessTotal": 0},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 3,"assessReason": "","assessAmount": "0","assessPenalty": "0","assessTotal": 0},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 1,"assessReason": "A","assessAmount": "1","assessPenalty": "2","assessTotal": 3},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 2,"assessReason": "B","assessAmount": "3","assessPenalty": "4","assessTotal": 7},{"assessmentType": "FINAL","assessCatId": 3,"assessReason": "C","assessAmount": "5","assessPenalty": "6","assessTotal": 11}];
const output = user_profile.filter(({assessCatId, assessReason}) => assessCatId > 0 && assessReason);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
var res = arr.filter( el => el.assessCatId > 0 && el.assessCatId < 4 && el.assessReason  ) ;
```

```js
var arr = [  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
]


var res = arr.filter( el => el.assessCatId > 0 && el.assessCatId < 4 && el.assessReason  ) ;

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{ "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": -1, "assessReason": "2", "assessAmount": "", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": -1, "assessReason": "2", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": -1, "assessReason": "", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": null, "assessAmount": "", "assessPenalty": "", "assessTotal": 0 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": null, "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": "", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": "", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": "2075-09-09", "assessAmount": "2075-09-17", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": "2075-09-09", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 0, "assessReason": "2075-09-17", "assessTotal": null }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 1, "assessReason": "", "assessAmount": "0", "assessPenalty": "0", "assessTotal": 0 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 2, "assessReason": "", "assessAmount": "0", "assessPenalty": "0", "assessTotal": 0 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 3, "assessReason": "", "assessAmount": "0", "assessPenalty": "0", "assessTotal": 0 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 1, "assessReason": "A", "assessAmount": "1", "assessPenalty": "2", "assessTotal": 3 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 2, "assessReason": "B", "assessAmount": "3", "assessPenalty": "4", "assessTotal": 7 }, { "assessmentType": "FINAL", "assessCatId": 3, "assessReason": "C", "assessAmount": "5", "assessPenalty": "6", "assessTotal": 11 }]
var o = arr.filter((f) => [1, 2, 3].indexOf(f.assessCatId) != -1 && f.assessReason)
console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace  by `({ assessCatId,assessReason })=>assessCatId>0 && assessReason!='')`

```js
var user_profile = [  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
];


const output = user_profile.filter(({ assessCatId,assessReason })=>assessCatId>0 && assessReason!='');
  
  console.log("output", output.length, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = [];
for(var i=0; i < user_profile.length; i++){
    var assessCatId = user_profile[i].assessCatId;
    var assessReason = user_profile[i].assessReason;
    if((assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && (assessReason != '' && assessReason != null)){
        output.push(user_profile[i]);
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you should first try the basic `for loop` then you should dive
>   to the array helper/prototype functions. This will help you to
>   understand whats going on.

```js
function test() {
  var data = [{
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": -1,
      "assessReason": "2",
      "assessAmount": "",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": -1,
      "assessReason": "2",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": -1,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": null,
      "assessAmount": "",
      "assessPenalty": "",
      "assessTotal": 0
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": null,
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": "2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount": "2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": "2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 0,
      "assessReason": "2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal": null
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 1,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessAmount": "0",
      "assessPenalty": "0",
      "assessTotal": 0
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 2,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessAmount": "0",
      "assessPenalty": "0",
      "assessTotal": 0
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 3,
      "assessReason": "",
      "assessAmount": "0",
      "assessPenalty": "0",
      "assessTotal": 0
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 1,
      "assessReason": "A",
      "assessAmount": "1",
      "assessPenalty": "2",
      "assessTotal": 3
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 2,
      "assessReason": "B",
      "assessAmount": "3",
      "assessPenalty": "4",
      "assessTotal": 7
    },
    {
      "assessmentType": "FINAL",
      "assessCatId": 3,
      "assessReason": "C",
      "assessAmount": "5",
      "assessPenalty": "6",
      "assessTotal": 11
    }
  ]

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var current_node = data[i];
    var filtered = [];
    if ((current_node.assessCatId >= 1 && current_node.assessCatId <= 3) && (current_node.assessReason != '' && current_node.assessReason != null)) {
      filtered.push(current_node);
    }
  }
  return filtered;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(test()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter function and use second `this` parameter to pass array of CatIds.  Test that the current element's id is included in the CatIds and use the fact that defined, non-empty strings are truthy, falsey otherwise.

```js
const arr = [  
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"2",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":-1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessAmount":"",
      "assessPenalty":"",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":null,
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessAmount":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-09",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":0,
      "assessReason":"2075-09-17",
      "assessTotal":null
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"",
      "assessAmount":"0",
      "assessPenalty":"0",
      "assessTotal":0
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":1,
      "assessReason":"A",
      "assessAmount":"1",
      "assessPenalty":"2",
      "assessTotal":3
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":2,
      "assessReason":"B",
      "assessAmount":"3",
      "assessPenalty":"4",
      "assessTotal":7
   },
   {  
      "assessmentType":"FINAL",
      "assessCatId":3,
      "assessReason":"C",
      "assessAmount":"5",
      "assessPenalty":"6",
      "assessTotal":11
   }
];

const catIds = [1, 2, 3];

// return elements with acceptable catId (id matches at least one) and truthy reason (non-empty, non-null, non-undefined)
function filterFn({ assessCatId: id, assessReason: reason }) {
  return this.includes(id) && !!reason
};

const res = arr.filter(filterFn, catIds);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of || because in the case of &&, true is returned when both the conditions are true whereas in the case of || true is returned if either of the conditions is true.
Since in your case you want both assessCatId!=0 and assessReason= not empty,
So for this && will work.

**Code Snippet**

(assessCatId >= 1 && assessCatId <= 3) && (assessReason != '' && assessReason != null)